# How can I do query oracle for between two dates on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter, date

I need help, I have a query at codeIgniter like this

```
select * 
from meter_list 
where metertimestamp BETWEEN 
                     to_date('2010/03/15 05:06', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') 
                     and 
                     to_date('2015/03/15 05:06', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI');
```

I was trying like this in my code:

```
$this->_db_oracle->where('METERTIMESTAMP >=', $tgl1);
$this->_db_oracle->where('METERTIMESTAMP <=', $tgl2);
$query = $this->_db_oracle->get('MTR_METERLIST');
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Error Number:
>
> SELECT * FROM "MTR_METERLIST" WHERE "METERTIMESTAMP" > 0 AND "METERTIMESTAMP" < 0
>
> Line Number: 330

please help solve my code. sorry for my bad english, thanks

Comment: Looking at your Error feedback, I believe you cant compare datetimestamp data type with number data type

Comment: Check for the values of $tgl1 and $tgl2, also you can use BETWEEN in active record.

$this->db->where("METERTIMESTAMP BETWEEN $tgl1 AND $tgl2");

Just make sure to convert to proper sql date format if necessary.

Comment: @joseconsador okay I will try it

Answer (score -1):

Just try with code and use  "query" for fire SQL on oracle.
Like:

```
  public function __construct(){
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->_KISS_DB = $this->CI->load->database('kiss', TRUE);
    }

    function current_semester(){

            $strSQL = "select * from meter_list where metertimestamp BETWEEN 
                         to_date('2010/03/15 05:06', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') 
                         and 
                         to_date('2015/03/15 05:06', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI') ";

            $query = $this->_KISS_DB->query($strSQL);

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
               echo $row->COURSE_CODE;
            }
    }
```

Comment: wow I can use method query() like that? I will trying. btw your code `$this->CI =& get_instance();` for what? what's differences with `parent::__construct();` ? thanks for your reply

Comment: hey vikram how about injection issue for using this guide?

Comment: this work on my code, but i can inject sql. like entering username (e.g john or 1='1)